# How can I remove leading and trailing quotes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server database with an NTEXT column.  This column may contain data that is enclosed with double quotes. When I query for this column, I want to remove these leading and trailing quotes.

For example:

*"this is a test message"*

should become

*this is a test message*

I know of the LTRIM and RTRIM functions but these workl only for spaces.  Any suggestions on which functions I can use to achieve this.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: How can i perform below : insert into log(err1) values(“invalid column :’cc.name’”); how can i remove single quotes from this.

Answer (score 71):

I have just tested this code in MS SQL 2008 and validated it.

Remove left-most quote:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldName = SUBSTRING(FieldName, 2, LEN(FieldName))
WHERE LEFT(FieldName, 1) = '"'
```

Remove right-most quote: (Revised to avoid error from implicit type conversion to int)

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldName = SUBSTRING(FieldName, 1, LEN(FieldName)-1)
WHERE RIGHT(FieldName, 1) = '"'
```

Comment: ntext column, so LEN, LEFT & RIGHT won't work.  You should change to DataLength and SubString instead.

Comment: SUBSTRING is the function in SQL Server. Not SUBSTR

Comment: For anyone following, you can also set `WHERE FieldName LIKE '"%' for left quotes. (reverse the wildcard position for right quotes)

Answer (score 41):

I thought this is a simpler script if you want to remove all quotes

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET col_name = REPLACE(col_name, '"', '')
```

Comment: He only asked to remove leading and trailing quotes, this solution replaces all the quotes...

Answer (score 7):

My solution is to use the difference in the the column values length compared the same column length but with the double quotes replaced with spaces and trimmed in order to calculate the start and length values as parameters in a SUBSTRING function.

The advantage of doing it this way is that you can remove any leading or trailing character even if it occurs multiple times whilst leaving any characters that are contained within the text.

Here is my answer with some test data:

```
 SELECT 
  x AS before
  ,SUBSTRING(x 
       ,LEN(x) - (LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(x, '"', ' ')) + '|') - 1) + 1 --start_pos
       ,LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(x, '"', ' '))) --length
       ) AS after
FROM 
(
SELECT 'test'     AS x UNION ALL
SELECT '"'        AS x UNION ALL
SELECT '"test'    AS x UNION ALL
SELECT 'test"'    AS x UNION ALL
SELECT '"test"'   AS x UNION ALL
SELECT '""test'   AS x UNION ALL
SELECT 'test""'   AS x UNION ALL
SELECT '""test""' AS x UNION ALL
SELECT '"te"st"'  AS x UNION ALL
SELECT 'te"st'    AS x
) a
```

Which produces the following results:

```
before  after
-----------------
test    test
"   
"test   test
test"   test
"test"  test
""test  test
test""  test
""test""    test
"te"st" te"st
te"st   te"st
```

One thing to note that when getting the length I only need to use LTRIM and not LTRIM and RTRIM combined, this is because the LEN function does not count trailing spaces.

Comment: This is the best answer.  It ONLY removes beginning and end double quotes and it then also can detect multiple beginning and end double quotes and remove those as well.  Last it leaves in place any double quotes within the string.  Perfection.  It can be run multiple times repeatedly and maintain the same results.  It is idempotent.

Comment: I actually discovered one issue with this... I was running this against ALL of the data in my columns however I discovered that if this is run on fields that contain no beginning or ending double quotes and also has white space at the end, this script will remove the white space AND the character before the white space at the end.  Be cautious... I almost ran this against Production data before I found this issue.  I need to cleanup data and this was almost perfect... still the closest thing to get the job done that I've found.  I am first using RTRIM(LTRIM(myfield)) then running this script.

Comment: Ok to Fix the issue if the script is run again on data having spaces in between the double quotes I added a REPLACE into the LENGTH portion so it can count trailing spaces.

 ,SUBSTRING(x 
       ,LEN(x) - (LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(x, '"', ' ')) + '|') - 1) + 1 --start_pos
       ,LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(x, ' ', 'X'), '"', ' '))) --length
       ) AS afterNEW

Comment: @Dave Sexton - It's not often that I bookmark a solution.  Thank you for the incredibly clever method.  I also love it when people build in the proof.  Very well done.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the "Replace" function in SQL Server.

like this ::

```
select REPLACE('this is a test message','"','')
```

note: second parameter here is "double quotes" inside two single quotes and third parameter is simply a combination of two single quotes. The idea here is to replace the double quotes with a blank.

Very simple and easy to execute !

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older question post, but my daughter came to me with the question, and referenced this page as having possible answers. Given that she's hunting an answer for this, it's a safe assumption others might still be as well.

All are great approaches, and as with everything there's about as many way to skin a cat as there are cats to skin.

If you're looking for a left trim *and* a right trim of a character or string, *and* your trailing  character/string is uniform in length, here's my suggestion:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColName,VAR, LEN(ColName)-VAR)
```

Or in this question...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('"this is a test message"',2, LEN('"this is a test message"')-2)
```

With this, you simply adjust the SUBSTRING starting point (2), and LEN position (-2) to whatever value you need to remove from your string.

It's non-iterative and doesn't require explicit case testing and above all it's *inline* all of which make for a cleaner execution plan.

Comment: Also was looking for an answer to this, and using mysql and I had to replace LEN with LENGTH, but otherwise this answer was perfect for me.

Comment: If your plan is to apply this against all data in a column it will of course strip out any character at the beginning and end... not just double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

The following script removes quotation marks only from around the column value if table is called [Messages] and the column is called [Description].

```
-- If the content is in the form of "anything" (LIKE '"%"')
-- Then take the whole text without the first and last characters 
-- (from the 2nd character and the LEN([Description]) - 2th character)

UPDATE [Messages]
SET [Description] = SUBSTRING([Description], 2, LEN([Description]) - 2)
WHERE [Description] LIKE '"%"'
```

Comment: For MySQL, replace ```LEN()``` with ```LENGTH()```.

Answer (score 4):

You can use following query which worked for me-

For updating-

```
UPDATE table SET colName= REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(colName, '"', ''))), '', '"') WHERE...
```

For selecting-

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(colName, '"', ''))), '', '"') FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TRIM('"' FROM '"this "is" a test"')` which returns: `this "is" a test`

Answer (score 2):

you could replace the quotes with an empty string...

```
SELECT AllRemoved = REPLACE(CAST(MyColumn AS varchar(max)), '"', ''),
       LeadingAndTrailingRemoved = CASE 
           WHEN MyTest like '"%"' THEN SUBSTRING(Mytest, 2, LEN(CAST(MyTest AS nvarchar(max)))-2)
           ELSE MyTest
           END  
FROM   MyTable
```

Comment: there may be quotes within the string and I don't want to remove these - just the leading and trailing quotes.

Comment: updated example to a case statement to remove just leading and trailing when both are present.

Answer (score 2):

Some UDFs for re-usability.

Left Trimming by character (any number)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LTRIMCHAR] (@Input NVARCHAR(max), @TrimChar CHAR(1) = ',')
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
      RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Input,' ','¦'), @TrimChar, ' ')), ' ', @TrimChar),'¦',' ')
END
```

Right Trimming by character (any number)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RTRIMCHAR] (@Input NVARCHAR(max), @TrimChar CHAR(1) = ',')
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
     RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Input,' ','¦'), @TrimChar, ' ')), ' ', @TrimChar),'¦',' ')
END
```

Note the dummy character '¦' (Alt+0166) cannot be present in the data (you may wish to test your input string, first, if unsure or use a different character).

Answer (score 1):

To remove both quotes you could do this

```
SUBSTRING(fieldName, 2, lEN(fieldName) - 2)
```

you can either assign or project the resulting value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT left(right(cast(SampleText as nVarchar),LEN(cast(sampleText as nVarchar))-1),LEN(cast(sampleText as nVarchar))-2)
  FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@String VARCHAR(MAX), @Char varchar(5))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
RETURN SUBSTRING(@String,PATINDEX('%[^' + @Char + ' ]%',@String)
    ,(DATALENGTH(@String)+2 - (PATINDEX('%[^' + @Char + ' ]%'
    ,REVERSE(@String)) + PATINDEX('%[^' + @Char + ' ]%',@String)
    )))
END
GO

Select dbo.TRIM('"this is a test message"','"')
```

Reference : http://raresql.com/2013/05/20/sql-server-trim-how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-charactersspaces-from-string/

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
UPDATE DataImport
SET PRIO = 
        CASE WHEN LEN(PRIO) < 2 
        THEN 
            (CASE PRIO WHEN '""' THEN '' ELSE PRIO END) 
        ELSE REPLACE(PRIO, '"' + SUBSTRING(PRIO, 2, LEN(PRIO) - 2) + '"', 
            SUBSTRING(PRIO, 2, LEN(PRIO) - 2)) 
        END
```