# SQLite update to change double-double quotes ("") to regular quotation marks (")?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

working on an iPhone app. I just imported some records into a SQL Lite database, and all my regular quote marks have been "doubled". An example:

Desired final format:
The song "ABC" will play at 3 PM.

The record is currently appearing in the database as:

The song ""ABC"" will play at 3 PM.

Does anyone know how to do a SQL update to change all "double-double" quotes to just regular quotation marks?

Just to clarify, I'm looking directly at the database, not via code. The code will just display these as "double-double" quotes just as they appear in the database, so I want to remove them. The "double-double" quotes are actually in the import file as well, but if I try to remove them, then the import fails. So I kept them there, and now that the records are successfully imported into the database, now I just want to correct the "double-double" quote thing with a mass SQL update if it's possible. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: How are you displaying this result? This is most likely just the way the value is displayed. If you read the value through code, does the resulting value actually have the extra quotes?

Comment: I dont know if sqllite supports these functions but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1066162/442328) could help.

Comment: KDaker, thanks for the suggestion, but that question was for removing quotes at the beginning of each record -- my "double-double" quotes are at all different parts of multiple records, hence my difficulty in figuring out if a SQL update can actually correct the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Given your update, the problem is how you parse the import file. Parse the file properly and you won't end up putting double-quotes in the database.

Comment: Actually, the double-double quotes are added by Excel when the Excel file is saved as a tab-delimited file. Thus it's not about the import process, because they're already there before I start the import process. And yet, if I remove them before the import process, the import fails, probably due to apostrophes that are also present in the  records. So the best success I've had to this point is to import with the double-double quotes, so if I can remove them from the records that are now in the database, I'm golden! Thanks

Comment: But that's my point. The double-double quotes are part of the imported file. This is a standard CSV (TSV) file format. Quotes get doubled up. This is how they are escaped. As you parse the csv file, you need to deal with the escaped quotes and possible newlines in a value, etc. Parsing CSV data is not trivial. BTW - you don't make it clear how you import the csv file into SQLite. My response assumes you are parsing the csv file yourself in Objective-C. Is this what you are doing or are you using the sqlite command line to import the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite uses single quotes to escape string literals. It escapes single quotes by adding another single quote (likewise for double quotes). So technically as long as your SQL is well constructed, the import process should work properly. The strings should be enclosed in single quotes, and not double quotes. I suspect that your code may be constructing the SQL by hand instead of binding/properly escaping the values.

SQLite has a built in function to quote string's. It's called quote. Here are some sample inputs, and the corresponding output:

```
sqlite> SELECT quote("foo");
'foo'
sqlite> SELECT quote("foo ""bar""");
'foo "bar"'
sqlite> SELECT quote("foo 'bar'");
'foo ''bar'''
```

So you could remove the twice escaped double quote before it even goes to SQLite using NSString methods.

```
[@"badString\"\"" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"\"" withString:@"\""];
```

If the database already contains bad values, then you could run the following update SQL to clean it up:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, '""', '"');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Anurag, that last SQL statement may do the trick! I'm using a Mac-based app called "Base" to do the import, so I'm not sure what the SQL is they're using within the app to do the import. But now that I have the data in there, the update statement you provided may be just what I need to correct the data. Thank you so much for the insight as well, much appreciated!