# Running SQL query to remove all trailing and beginning double quotes only affects first record in result set

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having a problem when running the below query - it seems to ONLY affect the very first record.  The query removes all trailing and beginning double quotes.  The first query is the one that does this; the second query is just to demonstrate that there are multiple records that have beginning double quotes that I need removed.

**QUESTION**: As you can see the first record resulting from the top query is fine - it has its double quotes removed from the beginning.  But all subsequent queries appear to be untouched.  Why?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `WHERE [Message] LIKE '"%'`?, how many rows does it return?

Comment: Just tried that, that returns the same number of rows, indicating to me that the rows where it appears the double quotes are in fact the beginning character is in fact the beginning character... hmm.. weird.

Comment: Is there any "come in the middle of the message?

Comment: Also, your `CASE` expression will remove either the beginning or trailing quotes, not both

Comment: @Lamak always the trailing one actually. Anything matching the second expression always matches the first.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, well, unless there's only a beginning one

Comment: Which is presumably the case in the first row.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's the most probable case here

Comment: @MikeMarks what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066134/how-can-i-remove-leading-and-trailing-quotes-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

If quotes are always assumed to exist at both the beginning and the end, adjust your CASE statement to look for instances where both cases exist:

```
CASE
WHEN ([Message] LIKE '"%' AND [Message] LIKE '%"') THEN LEFT(RIGHT([Message], LEN([Message])-1),LEN([Message]-2)
ELSE [Message]
```

EDIT

If assumption is not valid, combine above syntax with your existing CASE logic:

```
CASE
WHEN ([Message] LIKE '"%' AND [Message] LIKE '%"') THEN LEFT(RIGHT([Message],LEN([Message])-1),LEN([Message]-2)
WHEN ([Message] LIKE '"%') THEN RIGHT([Message],LEN([Message]-1)
WHEN ([Message] LIKE '%"') THEN LEFT([Message],LEN([Message]-1)
ELSE [Message]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your CASE statement is only evaluating the first condition met, it will only ever remove one of the statements.

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Message, 1, 1), '"', '') + SUBSTRING(Message, 2, LEN(Message) - 2) + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Message, LEN(Message), 1), '"', '')
```

EDIT: As Martin Smith pointed out, my original code wouldn't work if a string was under two characters, so ...

```
CREATE TABLE #Message (Message VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #Message (Message)

SELECT '"SomeText"'
UNION 
SELECT '"SomeText'
UNION 
SELECT 'SomeText"'
UNION 
SELECT 'S'

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(Message) >=2 
        THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Message, 1, 1), '"', '') + SUBSTRING(Message, 2, LEN(Message) - 2) + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Message, LEN(Message), 1), '"', '') 
        ELSE Message 
    END AS Message
FROM #Message


DROP TABLE #Message
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE([Message], '"', '') AS [Message] FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: This will also remove quotes in the middle of the text.